# How to marry GWT (RPC) on the server and Weld/CDI?

Tags: java, gwt, cdi, jboss-weld

The question under [integrating GWT with CDI (Seam/Weld)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809596/integrating-gwt-with-cdi-seam-weld) did'nt get a much of attention, so I try a second time. On the server side I want to use Weld/CDI (I am using Guice right now). In Guice I have a subclass of RemoteServiceServlet which is named in a module which itself is activated in an GuiceServletContextListener. Has anybody wrote some class to register a RemoteServiceServlet so that the GWT RPC endpoint gets the instances from Weld?

Comment: What is the technical reason for wanting to use CDI instead of Guice?

Comment: Isn't [Errai](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/ErraiCDI) exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: No, wrong answer :) Errai is NOT using Weld but simply Guice. And thus it is not CDI because Google Guice does not a CDI implementation.

Comment: Guice is not standard, has no auto-scanning, does not supprt common annotations and doesn't do eventing by default. It "just" a DI-container, but CDI is much more.

Answer (score 0):

If you use CDI (as part of an EE6 container), you can annotate your GWT RemoteServiceServlets with @WebServlet, and they'll be CDI beans. @Inject will work on them, even @PersistenceContext and @Resource and other stuff, if properly configured (EE servers don't need any configuration, for other web containers, see the Weld docs, they need some listeners configured in web.xml). I used this architecture many times.

What you mention in your other question ("Apparently CDI won't work with classes derived from javax.servlet.Servlet.") should not be true any more, as a commenter also pointed out, it's fixed in 1.1.

The only problem I see right now is that if I try to add an interceptor to my @WebServlet, the loading will fail because GWT RemoteServiceServlet declare some final methods (getSerializationPolicy), so it cannot make a proxy of it.